# Python @property Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow

Tags: python, oop, properties, decorator, getter-setter

I am learning the @property decorator in Python. In a toy example, I encountered an error I do not understand.

My toy class:

```
class ClassWithValidator:
    def __init__(self, attribute_1):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1

    @property
    def attribute_1(self):
        return self.attribute_1
    
    @attribute_1.setter
    def attribute_1(self, value):
        print("Setting attribute_1...")
        if value < 10:
            raise ValueError("attribute_1 cannot be greater or equal to 10!")
        else:
            self.attribute_1 = value
```

An attempt to create its instance:

`class_instance = ClassWithValidator(11)`

triggers the following error:

```
Setting attribute_1... # repeated multiple times before the following error message:
>Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

The fix for this is to replace `self.attribute_1` with `self._attribute_1` in both property and its setter:

```
class FixedClassWithValidator:
    def __init__(self, attribute_1):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1

    @property
    def attribute_1(self):
        return self._attribute_1
    
    @attribute_1.setter
    def attribute_1(self, value):
        print("Setting attribute_1...")
        if value < 10:
            raise ValueError("attribute_1 cannot be greater or equal to 10!")
        else:
            self._attribute_1 = value


class_instance = FixedClassWithValidator(11)
```

I know that an attribute name preceded with an underscore (here: `_attribute_1`) means that, by convention, it's private. However, I still do not understand why the first code results in a stack overflow.

Comment: Your code in `__init__()` overwrites the property `attribute_1`. Did you want to set `self._attribute_1`?

Comment: You should get a `RecursionError:`. In `__init__` you do `self.attribute_1 = attribute_1`. Now the attribute setter is called. And what does the setter do? The setter does `self.attribute_1 = value` which means it call itself again ... and again ... and again ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you get that error, you should get a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. The problem is the last line of the setter `self.attribute_1 = value`, which calls the setter again in an infinite loop.

Your second solution works perfectly, but you could also consider a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#validator-class) to validate your data.

```
class MinValidator:  # Descriptor
    def __init__(self, min_value):
        self.min_value = min_value
        
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        print(f"Setting {self.name}...")
        if value < self.min_value:
            raise ValueError(f"attribute_1 cannot be lower than {self.min_value}!")
        else:
            obj.__dict__[self.name] = value

class ClassWithValidator:
    attribute_1 = MinValidator(10)
    
    def __init__(self, attribute_1):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1
```